# Does jQuery has a limit on the size of uploaded files when using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload, wamp

I was wondering if jQuery uploading (via Ajax) has a size limit ? With more details : i'm building a form to upload multiple images on the server (for now, it's in local using wampserver).

Fact is, I can upload one, two or three images easily, but all the next ones do not work : it's like my php function does not receive any information (while the image is treated by jQuery).

I did the test with a lot of images, each time different ones, and the first two or three of them are uploading, but the others are not.

By the way, my jquery function treats each file one by one : once a file is treated, the next one's treatment starts.

Comment: Show some code for both front end and back-end, and tell us exactly where in the process things go wrong (if you know)

Comment: jquery has no limits beyond what the underlying JS engine imposes. but it's not just jquery/JS limits you have to worry about. if the underlying OS/browser can only handle (say) 2gig files, then there's nothing you can do in JS to work around that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit on the size of the upload files when using ajax. For example, in youtube or facebook (which use ajax to upload files) you can upload whatever you want without any restriction on the size of the uploaded files.

The reason that made your website fail when uploading large files is that you may not set the size of maximum upload files. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size), it may help you.

Comment: Thx budy, it appears it was a question of php.ini setting.
To be honest, I thought treating files one by one could avoid this problem but obviously, it does not !

And sorry for the duplicate topic, I looked for my question but as you can see, I'm not english and my keywors sucks....

Thx again